# ¿Cómo puedo darle una id dinámica a mi código js?

Tags: javascript

Necesito darle una id dinámica a mi código para poder después utilizar por ejemplo la constante input y unit cost para multiplicarlas; las de tagname me trae todo en un array, no sabría cómo modificarlas para tener solo el número de la única que necesito y multiplicarla por el costo unitario(unit cost * input). Sería:

```
function showData5(array){
  let htmlContenido = "";
 
  for (let i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    let item = array[i];
    htmlContenido += `<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
    <thead> <tr>
       
     <td><img src="${item.image}" width="50" height="50" alt=""  class="img-thumbnail" href="product-info.html"></td>
     <td>${item.name}</td>
     <td>${item.currency}${item.unitCost}</td>
     <td> <input type="number" id="cant${i}" class="cant" name="tentacles" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>
       <p id="valores"></p> </td>
     <td class="unitCost" id="cost${i}">${item.currency}${item.unitCost}</td>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     </table>
     </div>
 `;

 container.innerHTML = htmlContenido;
}
}

const cant = document.getElementsByClassName("cant");//si me funciona
const costUnit1 = document.getElementById("cost{i}");//no me funciona
const cant2 = document.getElementById("cant${1}");//no me funciona
const input = document.querySelector('input');//si me funciona
console.log(parseInt(input.value))
```

Comment: No logro entender bien lo que necesitas, favor ser más específico y dar algún caso de ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás realizando un planteamiento de un [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY) donde crees que es necesario conseguir una cosa para arreglar otra, como si no hubiera otra forma de conseguirlo. Tal como dice ese enlace:

> el usuario final intenta resolver el problema por su cuenta, y no
> comprende la naturaleza real del problema, creyendo que su problema
> real X ha sido casi resuelto, a excepción de algún pequeño detalle Y
> en su solución

Entiendo que quieres establecer los id para hacer los cálculos, pero eso ya lo estás haciendo bien, solo que después no sabes como manejarlos. Y aunque supieras hacerlo, quedaría todo demasiado engorroso.

Mi propuesta evita el uso de id y se basa en las clases para conseguir lo que creo que pretendes.

El código quedaría así (más abajo hay una explicación ampliada):

```js
let array = [{
    'image': 'https://verdecora.es/1217366-medium_default/pepino-ecologico.jpg',
    'name': 'pepino',
    'currency': '$',
    'unitCost': '100'
  },
  {
    'image': 'https://ametllerorigen.vtexassets.com/arquivos/ids/167269/000000000000000121-Pebrot-vermell-extra.jpg?v=637459726137530000',
    'name': 'pimiento',
    'currency': '$',
    'unitCost': '200'
  }
]

function showData5(array) {
  let htmlContenido = "";
  htmlContenido += `
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" id="listaItems">
          <thead></thead>
          <tbody>`

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let item = array[i];
    htmlContenido += `
    <tr>
        <td><img src="${item.image}" width="50" height="50" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" href="product-info.html"></td>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
        <td>${item.currency} <span class="unitCost">${item.unitCost}</span></td>
        <td> <input type="number" class="cant" name="tentacles" value="0" min="0" max="100"/></td>
        <td class="subtotal">Subtotal</td>
    </tr>`;
  }
  htmlContenido += `
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>`
  container.innerHTML = htmlContenido;
}

// mostramos la tabla
showData5(array)

// ponemos a la escucha el evento del teclado keyup en toda la tabla
listaItems.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  // si el evento lo ha provocado el elemento con la clase cant
  if (e.target.classList.contains("cant")) {
    // conseguimos las unidades
    let unidades = Number(e.target.value)
    // conseguimos el coste
    let coste = Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.unitCost').textContent)
    // establecemos el subtotal
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.subtotal').textContent = unidades * coste
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container"></div>
```

### Cambios realizados

1. Se han quitado todos los id (ya no los necesitamos) y se ha agregado un id a la definición de la tabla denominado `listaItems`
2. Se han quitado clases sobrantes y un parágrafo que no tenia contenido y que no afecta a tu pregunta y que además repetia el id en cada ciclo, y en HTML los **id siempre deben ser únicos** (las clases no hace falta).
3. He puesto un array de ejemplo con datos inventados
4. He quitado la cabecera y pie de tabla del bucle pues en tu código creabas muchas tablas en lugar de solo filas (aunque aparentemente son muy parecidos, pero a nivel de código lo sobrecargabas innecesariamente). Ahora tan solo se crean filas en el bucle.
5. He agregado un `<span class="unitCost"></span>` que delimita el importe, para separarlo del simbolo de moneda
6. He creado una columna de subtotal que recibirá el importe calculado de unidades * coste cada vez que se modifique el valor del input en cada línea
7. He quitado esto `container.innerHTML = htmlContenido;` del bucle porque lo repetias constantemente y tan solo hace falta hacerlo una vez al final
8. He agregado la escucha del evento `keyup` en la tabla `listaItems` mediante [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
9. He eliminado una columna que tenias repetida y he creado una nueva que contendrá el subtotal calculado de cada fila con la clase `subtotal`

El resto está explicado en los comentarios del código, donde se han usado estos nuevos métodos o propiedades:

- [e.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target): Identifica el elemento que recibe el evento `keyup`
- [classList.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList): Busca una clase entre las clases del elemento
- [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode): Sube un elemento en la jerarquía de elementos
- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number): Convierte a número una cadena de texto
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent): Lee o establece el contenido de texto del elemento